# When Using Pipes And Forks

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, system-calls

I have a simple program(**maximum1**) that prints the highest number inside a file. The challenge was to use forks and pipes to run through multiple files with multiple processes and print the highest number from those files. I have the first program down so that it prints the number but when I use the second program(**maximum2**), I am getting larger numbers than what is in the file.

I think the problem is in my use of the pipes or not understanding the transfer to num1. Thanks for any help!

```
  if ((childpid1 = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("Fork1 Error.\n");
} else if (childpid1 == 0) {      //Child Code

 close(fd[0]);
 dup2(fd[1], 1);
 dup2(fd[1], 2);
 close(fd[1]);

 execl ("max1", "max1", argv[1], NULL);
 perror("Failed Exec.\n"); //Make sure Execl works

} else {              //Parent Code
 waitpid(childpid1, &status, 0);
 char buffer[1024];

 close(fd[0]);

 read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));

 sscanf( buffer, "%d", &num1);
 printf("%d\n", num1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your parent process's code, you do this:

```
//Parent Code
waitpid(childpid1, &status, 0);
char buffer[1024];

close(fd[0]);

read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));

sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num1);
printf("%d\n", num1);
```

So you close `fd[0]`, which I guess is your pipe's read end, and then you try to `read` from it.

That read should return you an `EBADF` error, which you never check. So you probably just print garbage on output.

Change your `read(...)` to this:

```
if (read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) < 0) {
    perror("read");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and see yourself what happens.

What you probably need to do is close the write end of the pipe for the parent process. So change `close(fd[0])` to:

```
if (close(fd[1]) < 0) {
    perror("close");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and always mind how important it is to check system calls' return values.

Comment: Thank you for that! Did not see that I had switched them.